# How to set different formfield_for_foreignkey option list for different form like add and change

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin-filters

I defined a model named Emp (employees) as below:

```python
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Emp(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empid = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    cnname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    joindate = models.DateField()
    islogi = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    isleave = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    leavedate = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

In Admin.py I have following code:

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Emp

class EmpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','empid','cnname','gender','birthdate','joindate',
        'islogi','isleave','leavedate')

    ordering = ('empid',)
    search_fields = ['empid','cnname']
    list_per_page = 12
    exclude = ('isleave','leavedate',)

    # for list view, if not admin just show emp self info
    # for admin all employees will be listed.
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            user = get_user_model()
            return qs.filter(empid=Emp.objects.get(user_id=user.objects.get(username=request.user).id).empid)

    # this is used for form add and change actions
    # but I want to add and change have different option list
    # add just list the users which are not employees
    # change list the users which are not employees + employee self
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print("self", self)
        print("db_field", db_field)
        print("build_absolute_uri() => ", request.build_absolute_uri())

        if db_field.name == 'user':
            print("kwargs => ", kwargs)

            users = get_user_model()
            u = users.objects.all()
            uidlist = []
            for x in range(len(u)):
                uidlist.append(u[x].id)

            e = Emp.objects.all()
            for x in range(len(e)):
                uidlist.remove(e[x].user_id)

            kwargs["queryset"] = users.objects.filter(id__in=uidlist)

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


admin.site.register(Emp, EmpAdmin)
```

Above "formfield_for_foreignkey" it list the same option list for "user"  option list. How can I override the list for "add" and "change" actions, so they can use different option lists?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the request that is passed in to check if the request is a change or add:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if "/add/" in request.path:
        #add logic
    elif "/change/" in request.path:
        #change logic
```